# Normalization of database according to the given data

Tags: normalization, denormalization

I'm creating new database based on existing database, performing some normalization. Here is the table containing multiple information, it's basically for booking trips etc
[image]

I've divided all the info into some tables, I need some expert advice whether is it correct or I need to make some changes?
[image: relationship]

Comment: Where did all the IDs come from? I see only `TripID` in the data.

Comment: It is not correct.  What are the functional dependencies in the table?

Comment: DavidBrowne-Microsoft Only the tripName is the one which is functionaly dependent on TripId others are not.